# What is a faster way to insert every variation of a large datatable of 280,000 records into another table?

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql, bigdata

I have a table with LocationID, Lat, Long of 280,000 records.

I want to insert every variation of matches into a new table.

Example, with records A, B and C I would end up with AB, BC, and AC

My TSQL Query is

```
INSERT INTO Distances (ID1, ID2, Distance)
SELECT a1.ID, a2.ID, 0
FROM Location a1 
JOIN Location a2 ON a1.ID <> a2.ID
```

I then wish to run another query that will update the Distance column from 0 using a working scalar function and the lat and longs. However, just the insert statement is taking 40 + minutes to run.

I thought I could save the Locations table into a faster database (maybe JsonDB?) but have not experience with other databases and am not sure which would be fastest.

I am running windows 10 and prefer a gui. 
The database for processing must allow for scalar style functions that can do math operations on the lat/longs.

Any suggestions?

Comment: @PieterGeerkens, he is inserting `~280,000 * 280,000 / 2 = 39,200,000,000` rows. It will take a while with any database.

Comment: @VladimirBaranov: Ah so. Yes, my laptop will struggle to do 39 billion inserts efficiently.

Comment: Try to compare the performance on a smaller set and calculate distance in the `INSERT` query straight away instead of inserting 0 and then updating all rows again. Quite likely it will be more efficient to calculate distance in the `INSERT`. BTW, SQL Server has built-in [spatial functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933790.aspx). PostgreSQL also supports spatial types and functions.

Comment: @VladimirBaranov your mention of spatial functions just cut down some of my queries from 9 seconds round trip to .8 second. Again, how I have been programming this long without coming across that is beyond me. BUT THANKS FOR MENTIONING IT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have no indexes defined and add the hint "WITH (TABLOCKX)" after the table name. That should give you "simple logging" on the table and should be somewhat faster.

Also,  do the calculation as part of the insert.  An update on such a large table will give you a MASSIVE transaction journal,  and may even fail because of the size of it.  When doing large updates on SQL Server, it can be more effective to create a new table than to update an existing one, because an insert can be persuaded to do simple logging rather than full logging.

You can also halve the size of your table by realising that it is actually symmetrical;  run the join as "<" rather than "<>". If you really need both directions you can create a view on top afterwards.